# Linux CentOS grep expression

Tags: linux, centos, files, grep

I am trying to find a grep expression that will find an IP address in any file within every file and directory.

I have not mastered grep yet, but think there "should be?" something simple.
Any thoughts?

Comment: This page may be of use to you: https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html

Comment: @Snowcat, if your question is answered, please accept the answer below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The extended pattern that matches things that look like IPv4 addresses and are only between the range of 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255 is:

`((2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|(1[0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|[0-9])\.((2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|(1[0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|[0-9])\.((2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|(1[0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|[0-9])\.((2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|(1[0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|[0-9])`

You'll need to use `egrep` (or `grep -E`) with this expression and with all that follow.

Note that this will catch weird outliers like 1111.2.3.444 as well, because it will match `111.2.3.44`.  (There are more sophisticated tests that can be written, but they're even less readable.)

If you don't care about 1111.2.3.444, *and* you don't care about things like 999.000.011.555 matching, the simpler regex, suggested by ilkkachu in the comments, is `([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}`.

To look in all directories, you'll probably want to incorporate `find` as well:

`find /var/log -type f -exec egrep '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' '{}' +`

This uses the GNU `find` behavior of using `+` to make a single command line instead of running `grep` on each file in series, and in turn relies on `grep` printing the name of matching files first (which almost every `grep`does).

Detecting IPv6 addresses is outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: Note to the OP: You may consider storing one section of the pattern in a variable and then construct the complete pattern by something like "$a.$a.$a.$a" instead of typing this long regex explicitly.

Comment: Hey Ben.  Thank you for putting that information out there.  Could you write an example for me, and I could learn from that.  I don't know the difference between egrep, grep and isn't there an fgrep or something.   Anyway, if you could write an example, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: `([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}` ? Though if you want to check that it's surrounded by something else, you'd need to decide what counts as a proper delimiter.

Comment: @BenStern, no, that should be an ERE. works with `grep -E` on my systems.

Comment: @ilkkachu, right you are!